# Docker daemon no longer start with kernel 3.19.0-21

Tags: kernel, 15.04, docker

On Tuesday this week, I received a Kernel update from 3.19.0-20 to 3.19.0-21 on my laptop (Latitude E6520). At reboot I had kernel panics, so I picked 3.19.0-20 from the boot menu and all was well for the rest of the day. The day after (i.e. yesterday), kernel 3.19.0-21 booted without problem, and everything was running OK **except** the Docker daemon. Rebooting with kernel 3.19.0-20 fixes it. Anyone has an idea how to possibly unblock it? Otherwise I'll set 3.19.0-20 as my default kernel until the next update.

**UPDATE:** Docker 1.7 doesn't solve it. Log is different though (see below).

**With kernel 3.19.0-21 and Docker 1.7.0:**

```
Jun 19 10:06:35 E6520-2 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
Jun 19 10:06:35 E6520-2 systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
Jun 19 10:06:35 E6520-2 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Jun 19 10:06:35 E6520-2 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Jun 19 10:06:35 E6520-2 docker[3779]: time="2015-06-19T10:06:35.917685581+02:00" level=error msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver \"aufs\" failed: driver not supported"
Jun 19 10:06:35 E6520-2 docker[3779]: time="2015-06-19T10:06:35.917756197+02:00" level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported"
Jun 19 10:06:35 E6520-2 systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 19 10:06:35 E6520-2 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Jun 19 10:06:35 E6520-2 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

Relevant parts from `/var/log/syslog` this morning:

**With kernel 3.19.0-21:**

```
Jun 18 10:22:27 E6520-2 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Jun 18 10:22:27 E6520-2 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
…
Jun 18 10:22:27 E6520-2 docker[891]: time="2015-06-18T10:22:27+02:00" level=warning msg="Udev sync is not supported. This will lead to unexpected behavior, data loss and errors"
Jun 18 10:22:27 E6520-2 kernel: [    7.053225] device-mapper: table: 252:0: thin-pool: unknown target type
Jun 18 10:22:27 E6520-2 kernel: [    7.053229] device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
Jun 18 10:22:27 E6520-2 docker[891]: time="2015-06-18T10:22:27+02:00" level=info msg="+job serveapi(fd://)"
Jun 18 10:22:27 E6520-2 docker[891]: time="2015-06-18T10:22:27+02:00" level=info msg="Listening for HTTP on fd ()"
Jun 18 10:22:27 E6520-2 docker[891]: time="2015-06-18T10:22:27+02:00" level=fatal msg="Shutting down daemon due to errors: error intializing graphdriver: Error running DeviceCreate (CreatePool) dm_task_run failed"
Jun 18 10:22:27 E6520-2 systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 18 10:22:27 E6520-2 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Jun 18 10:22:27 E6520-2 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

**With kernel 3.19.0-20:**

```
Jun 18 10:23:16 E6520-2 docker[1000]: time="2015-06-18T10:23:16+02:00" level=info msg="+job serveapi(fd://)"
Jun 18 10:23:16 E6520-2 docker[1000]: time="2015-06-18T10:23:16+02:00" level=info msg="Listening for HTTP on fd ()"
…
Jun 18 10:23:16 E6520-2 kernel: [    7.009467] aufs 3.x-rcN-20150105
Jun 18 10:23:16 E6520-2 docker[1000]: time="2015-06-18T10:23:16+02:00" level=warning msg="Graphdriver aufs selected. Your graphdriver directory /var/lib/docker already contains data managed by other graphdrivers: devicemapper"
Jun 18 10:23:16 E6520-2 docker[1000]: time="2015-06-18T10:23:16+02:00" level=info msg="+job init_networkdriver()"
…
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 kernel: [    7.624158] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 systemd-udevd[358]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for docker0: No such file or directory
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 avahi-daemon[894]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface docker0.IPv4 with address 172.17.42.1.
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 avahi-daemon[894]: New relevant interface docker0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 avahi-daemon[894]: Registering new address record for 172.17.42.1 on docker0.IPv4.
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 NetworkManager[895]: nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 NetworkManager[895]: <info> (docker0): ignoring bridge not created by NetworkManager
…
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 NetworkManager[895]: <info> devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0, iface: docker0)
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 NetworkManager[895]: <info> device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0, iface: docker0): no ifupdown configuration found.
…
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 systemd[1]: Started ifup for docker0.
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 systemd[1]: Starting ifup for docker0...
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 sh[1047]: Unknown interface docker0
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 kernel: [    7.632620] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 docker[1000]: time="2015-06-18T10:23:17+02:00" level=info msg="-job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)"
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 docker[1000]: time="2015-06-18T10:23:17+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup swap limit."
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 systemd[1]: Scope libcontainer-1000-systemd-test-default-dependencies.scope has no PIDs. Refusing.
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 docker[1000]: time="2015-06-18T10:23:17+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 docker[1000]: ....................................
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 docker[1000]: time="2015-06-18T10:23:17+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 docker[1000]: time="2015-06-18T10:23:17+02:00" level=info msg="docker daemon: 1.6.2 7c8fca2; execdriver: native-0.2; graphdriver: aufs"
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 docker[1000]: time="2015-06-18T10:23:17+02:00" level=info msg="+job acceptconnections()"
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 docker[1000]: time="2015-06-18T10:23:17+02:00" level=info msg="-job acceptconnections() = OK (0)"
Jun 18 10:23:17 E6520-2 docker[1000]: time="2015-06-18T10:23:17+02:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looked like the Kernel wasn't properly installed: it also broke WiFi (`lspci -k` was showing no driver for my WiFi cart).

After several days running the old Kernel exclusively, and having issues with Docker there too (due to a breaking change in Docker 1.7, see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14035 ) I tried reinstalling the new Kernel (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.19.0-21-generic`) and it happened to work.

Answer (score 2):

Aufs is no longer included in the Ubuntu kernel package. (modprobe aufs will give an error)

Because [overlay](http://jpetazzo.github.io/assets/2015-03-03-not-so-deep-dive-into-docker-storage-drivers.html#52) is included since 3.18. So you can just use that for docker. (I have no idea about migration.)

Comment: But you can install `linux-image-extra` package and get aufs again.

Comment: docker recommended way to install `linux-image-exra` https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#prerequisites-by-ubuntu-version

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to either start the docker container directly:

I just started the docker deamon via:

```
$ sudo docker -d -s overlay
```

instead of

```
$ sudo docker -d
```

and it worked for me.

---

Yet since I wanted to run the docker daemon via

```
sudo service start docker
```

I had to edit the file:

```
$ vim /etc/default/docker 


# Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file

# Customize location of Docker binary (especially for development testing).
#DOCKER="/usr/local/bin/docker"

# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry my-repo.de:5000 -s overlay" // here be your config

# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.
#export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"

# This is also a handy place to tweak where Docker's temporary files go.
#export TMPDIR="/mnt/bigdrive/docker-tmp"
```